# Deep Q Learning - training slows down significantly

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning

I'm trying to build a deep Q network to play snake. I designed the game so that the window is 600 by 600 and the snake's head moves 30 pixels each tick. I implemented the DQN algorithm with memory replay and a target network, but as soon as the policy network starts updating its weights the training slows down significantly, to the point where each iteration of the weight update loop takes around 5 minutes. Additionally, I see almost no improvement in the agent's performance, even after training for around 500 episodes. Here's the code for the agent:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from snake_rl.envs.snake_env import SnakeEnv
import random
from Game.experience import Experience
import time
import pygame
from PIL import Image
from keras import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, Dense, BatchNormalization, Activation, Flatten, Reshape
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg


class Brain:
    def __init__(self, learning_rate, discount_rate, eps_start, eps_end, eps_decay, memory_size, batch_size, max_episodes, max_steps, target_update):
        self.memory = []
        self.push_count = 0
        self.learning_rate = learning_rate
        self.discount_rate = discount_rate
        self.eps_start = eps_start
        self.current_eps = eps_start
        self.eps_end = eps_end
        self.eps_decay = eps_decay
        self.memory_size = memory_size
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.max_steps = max_steps
        self.max_episodes = max_episodes
        self.current_episode = 1
        self.policy_model = None
        self.replay_model = None
        self.target_update = target_update
        pygame.init()
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 600))
        pygame.display.set_caption("Snake")       

    def build_model(self):
        self.policy_model = Sequential()
        self.policy_model.add(Conv2D(8, (5, 5), padding = 'same', activation = 'relu', data_format = "channels_last", input_shape = (600, 600, 2)))
        self.policy_model.add(Conv2D(16, (5, 5), padding="same", activation="relu"))
        self.policy_model.add(Conv2D(32, (5, 5), padding="same", activation="relu"))
        self.policy_model.add(Flatten())
        self.policy_model.add(Dense(16, activation = "relu"))
        self.policy_model.add(Dense(5, activation = "softmax"))
        self.policy_model.compile(optimizer = 'rmsprop', loss = 'mean_squared_error')

        self.replay_model = Sequential()
        self.replay_model.add(Conv2D(8, (5, 5), padding = 'same', activation = 'relu', data_format = "channels_last", input_shape = (600, 600, 2)))
        self.replay_model.add(Conv2D(16, (5, 5), padding="same", activation="relu"))
        self.replay_model.add(Conv2D(32, (5, 5), padding="same", activation="relu"))
        self.replay_model.add(Flatten())
        self.replay_model.add(Dense(16, activation = "relu"))
        self.replay_model.add(Dense(5, activation = "softmax"))
        self.replay_model.compile(optimizer = 'rmsprop', loss = 'mean_squared_error')
        print(self.policy_model.summary())

    def decay_epsilon(self, episode):
        self.current_eps = self.eps_end + (self.eps_start - self.eps_end) * np.exp(-self.eps_decay * episode)

    def push_memory(self, new_memory):
        if(len(self.memory) < self.memory_size):
            self.memory.append(new_memory)
        else:
            self.memory[self.push_count % self.memory_size] = new_memory
        self.push_count += 1

    def sample_memory(self):
        return random.sample(self.memory, self.batch_size)

    def can_sample_memory(self):
        return len(self.memory) >= self.batch_size

    def screenshot(self):
        data = pygame.image.tostring(self.screen, 'RGB')
        image = Image.frombytes('RGB', (600, 600), data)
        image = image.convert('LA')
        matrix = np.asarray(image.getdata(), dtype=np.uint8)
        matrix = (matrix - 128)/(128 - 1)
        matrix = np.reshape(matrix, (1, 600, 600, 2))
        return matrix

    def train(self):
        tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.ERROR)
        self.build_model()
        for episode in range(self.max_episodes):
            self.current_episode = episode
            env = SnakeEnv(self.screen)
            episode_reward = 0
            for timestep in range(self.max_steps):
                env.render(self.screen)
                state = self.screenshot()
                #state = env.get_state()
                action = None
                epsilon = self.current_eps
                if epsilon > random.random():
                    action = np.random.choice(env.action_space) #explore
                else:
                    values = self.policy_model.predict(state) #exploit
                    action = np.argmax(values)
                experience = env.step(action)
                if(experience['done'] == True):
                    episode_reward += experience['reward']
                    break
                episode_reward += experience['reward']
                self.push_memory(Experience(experience['state'], experience['action'], experience['reward'], experience['next_state']))
                self.decay_epsilon(episode)
                if self.can_sample_memory():
                    memory_sample = self.sample_memory()
                    X = []
                    Y = []
                    for memory in memory_sample:
                        memstate = memory.state
                        action = memory.action
                        next_state = memory.next_state
                        reward = memory.reward
                        max_q = reward + (self.discount_rate * self.replay_model.predict(next_state)) #bellman equation
                        X.append(memstate)
                        Y.append(max_q)
                    X = np.array(X)
                    X = X.reshape([-1, 600, 600, 2])
                    Y = np.array(Y)
                    Y = Y.reshape([128, 5])
                    self.policy_model.fit(X, Y)
            print("Episode: ", episode, " Total Reward: ", episode_reward)
            if episode % self.target_update == 0:
                self.replay_model.set_weights(self.policy_model.get_weights())
        self.policy_model.save_weights('weights.hdf5')
        pygame.quit()

    def render(self):
        self.env.render(self.screen)

    def choose_action(self, state):
        q_values = self.policy_model.predict(state)
        action = np.amax(q_values)
        return action

    def load(self):
        self.build_model()
        self.policy_model.load_weights("weights.hdf5")

    def play(self):
        for episode in range(100):
            env = SnakeEnv(self.screen)
            for timestep in range(1000):
                env.render(self.screen)
                pred = self.policy_model.predict(env.get_state())
                print(np.array(pred))
                action = np.amax(pred)
                d = env.step(action)
                if(d['done'] == True):
                    break
```

My hyperparameters are as follows:

```
learning_rate = 0.5
discount_rate = 0.99
eps_start = 1
eps_end = .01
eps_decay = .001
memory_size = 100000
batch_size = 128
max_episodes = 1000
max_steps = 5000
target_update = 10
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to speed up training and improve performance?

Answer (score 2):

```
def decay_epsilon(self, episode):
    self.current_eps = self.eps_end + (self.eps_start - self.eps_end) * np.exp(-self.eps_decay * episode)



// part of code from train()
epsilon = self.current_eps
            if epsilon > random.random():
                action = np.random.choice(env.action_space) #explore
            else:
                values = self.policy_model.predict(state) #exploit
                action = np.argmax(values)
```

#### Problem

When episodes grows from 1 to 1000, possibility of taking random action decrease from 100% to 36%. When episodes is 500, there's 40% of chance to take random actions.

#### My Solutions

1. Wait. 3000 episodes make it 5% of random action.
2. eps_decay = 0.006. When it's 500 episodes, random actions decrease to 5%.

Comment: Changed decay to .006, probably going to let it train for the whole day and see what happens